# How to get how many chars were written in a ostream with the operator<<? Or how to read what was written?

Tags: c++, string, ostream

1)
I want to make an overload in operator `<<` so I can print a matrix of templates T.

I want to use the operator `<<` of the template class and for it to be aligned I have to know the number of chars that were written and add spaces in the end until a certain number of characters.

However, I don't know how I can (if I can) get the string that was written or the number of characters that were written...

---

2)
I need to perform

```cpp
cout << myobject
```

several times in a for. However, this operator<< spends a lot of time so I would like to it just once and store its result.
What can I do to avoid making the same method over and over again?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can use Boost libraries, Boost.Iostreams has an easy way to find out how many characters were written to a stream: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/counter.html

Comment: Generally the way you want to approach aligning the output is to save the [std::ios_base::fmtflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) (see the `.flags()` member). You will then [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) once on the stream and [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) for each elements outputting your matrix and finally restore the original stream `fmtflags` you saved at the beginning.

Comment: This is a classic case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your real problem is how to print a matrix so that its columns are aligned in the output. However, you are asking how to find out how many characters are printed by the `operator<<` function.

Comment: You have two questions in your post that are completely unrelated. I think you should ask the second question in a separate post. [Edit] this post and keep just the first question.

Comment: @RSahu The two questions have the same solution.

Comment: @Kerndog73, Then I missing something from the questions. Please elaborate.

Comment: @RSahu I seems like a solution to the second question would be to use string streams to cache the result of `operator<<`.

Comment: @Kerndog73, absolutely. I still think that the two questions are separate enough that they should be asked in different posts.

Comment: I was wondering if you can use tabbing `\t` as an alternative approach. If T is a number, count the digits and for each 8 digits apply a tab. Then specialize for strings and floats to do the same thing. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for the first problem.

1. Use a `std::ostringstream` to write an element of the matrix.
2. Get the `std::string` from the `std::ostringstream`.
3. Write a function that adds padding to the left or right of a string so that the resultant string is of a given length.
4. Use the padded string to create the final output in `std::cout` or a `std::ofstream`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot. The most similar thing `std::ostream` provides is the `tellp` method, that gives you the position in the current file. Unfortunately, as you care about the position related to the last newline, this won't help you; besides, in many common cases this method isn't even implemented (what is the position in the standard output "file", or in a socket?).

As for extracting what was written, no again. The underlying `streambuf` doesn't have to keep this data around - in facts, it may even flush to the underlying device every single character as soon as it gets written (which is pretty much what happens with unbuffered output).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be of interest?

```
│1         2         300       │
│1         463       6         │
│165       286       34457     │

│1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  │
│0.000000  1.000000  0.000000  │
│0.000000  0.000000  1.000000  │

│Hello     World!    This      │
│is        a         test      │
│to        create    spaces    │
```

The code is rough and you will probably have to tweak it to compensate for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

I think you can also modify it so that you can utilize tabbing, which by default consumes 8 spaces.

Online code example: https://rextester.com/IFXUFZ49322